# React-native Animation.event style property is not supported

Tags: android, reactjs, animation, react-native

I have a problem with Animated.event with interpolate on scroll event. When I use Animated.event with

`useNativeDriver: true`

I receive next error:

`Style property 'height' is not supported by native animated module`

If I use `opacity` property - it works fine.

My code:

```
render() {
        this.yOffset = new Animated.Value(0);

        let event = Animated.event([
            {
                nativeEvent: {
                    contentOffset: {
                        y: this.yOffset
                    }
                }
            }
        ], {useNativeDriver: true});

        let opacity = this.yOffset.interpolate({
            inputRange: [0, 120],
            outputRange: [1, 0],
        });

        let height = this.yOffset.interpolate({
            inputRange: [0, 180],
            outputRange: [200, 100],
        });

        return (
            <View>
                <Header
                    style={{
                        opacity,
                        height
                    }}
                />


                <ScrollView
                    style={[
                        {
                            flexDirection: "column"
                        }
                    ]}
                    scrollEventThrottle={1}
                    onScroll={event}
                >

                    // some content

                </ScrollView>
            </View>
        );
    }
```

`opacity` - works.

`height` - didn't works.

Without `useNativeDriver: true` - all works fine.

Android Accelerated_x86 API 23

RN 0.43.0-rc.4

React 16.0.0-alpha.3

Problem exists also in RN 0.42.

Comment: do you still have the same question? :D

Answer (score 28):

As the React Native documentation says, you can only animate non-layout properties. `Transform` property is supported so you can use `transform.scaleY` instead of changing the `height`.

> Not everything you can do with Animated is currently supported in
>   Native Animated. The main limitation is that you can only animate
>   non-layout properties, things like transform, opacity and
>   backgroundColor will work but flexbox and position properties won't.

[Using Native Driver for Animated](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2017/02/14/using-native-driver-for-animated.html)

Comment: I want to cry. Literally.

Comment: This just shows how RN is not yet 1.0, but 0.43. A lot of work still to do.

Comment: No updated in RN 60.1.4, the good thing is `height` is work smooth in ios without nativedriver.

Comment: @ToraCode I was just about to use the `transform.scaleY` method before I saw your comment. Now, I only have to change one line of code. Nice.

Answer (score 17):

Just change:

`useNativeDriver: true`

to

`useNativeDriver: false`

Answer (score 16):

This error comes from [validateTransform](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/c3d072955024824d7ff6113fc9f642d25c462f16/Libraries/Animated/src/NativeAnimatedHelper.js#L219) function inside React Native lib.You can check the `TRANSFORM_WHITELIST` in [NativeAnimatedHelper](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/c3d072955024824d7ff6113fc9f642d25c462f16/Libraries/Animated/src/NativeAnimatedHelper.js#L186) for the property supported by animated module.

Currently, there are these props supported

```js
const TRANSFORM_WHITELIST = {
  translateX: true,
  translateY: true,
  scale: true,
  scaleX: true,
  scaleY: true,
  rotate: true,
  rotateX: true,
  rotateY: true,
  rotateZ: true,
  perspective: true,
};
```

'height' is not in `TRANSFORM_WHITELIST`; `scaleY` is.

Comment: There are more things allowed, that whitelist is related to just the available transfroms.

See the following link for EVERY supported property: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Animated/NativeAnimatedHelper.js#L225-L268

Answer (score 4):

You can use another property, using gesture handler, there area a example on react-native-gesture handler with PanGestureHandler API:

```
<Animated.View style={{bottom: 0, transform: [{ translateY: this._translateY },] }}>...
  <PanGestureHandler>...
    <Animated.View>...
      <View >....
```